# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_products_categories_CategoryId"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add a `Product` entity to the database, the `Product` contains another entity called `Category` which I'm going to include below. The problem is that I get an error while adding the item:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_products_categories_CategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "ElectronicStoreDB", table "dbo.categories", column 'CategoryId'

Here are the entities

```
public class Product 
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category 
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'm mapping a `SaveProductRequest` to `Product` entity in the `POST` method

```
public class ProductSaveRequest 
{
    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping process is:

```
// Products Mapping.
CreateMap<ProductSaveRequest, Product>();
```

The dbContext add code is:

```
public async Task AddAsync(Product product) 
{
    await context.products.AddAsync(product);
}
```

Any solutions why I'm facing this kind of issues?

Comment: What is the value of Category of the product you are adding?

Comment: @RyanThomas I'm sending a CategoryId only with the rest of the Product properties

Comment: @RyanThomas    any Ideas?

Comment: I think you need an explicit foreign key property on Product. Something like: `[ForeignKey(nameof(Category))] public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }`. Now AutoMapper is mapping it into a new Category object, which EF sees as a new entity, and it tries to insert a new row.

Comment: @juunas        Could you please explain more about the mapping? I'd really appreciate it if you write an answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by providing an explicit **CategoryId** as a **ForeignKey** in the Product model based on [juunas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658906/juunas) comment with a little change.

```
public class Product {

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long? Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```